# Loop over a function and store as list

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have the following function that clicks a checkbox with splash:

```
local get_dimensions = splash:jsfunc([[
        function () {
            for i=1, 5 do
            var rect = document.querySelector(string.format('checkbox[number="%d"]'), i)
            .getClientRects()[0];
            return {[rect.left]: rect.top};
    end
        }
    ]])
```

However, I cannot store a list from the loop into a single variable like `rect`, so how do I store a list into a variable, and when I return it, it should return a list of values?

Something similar to python, ie.:

```
def stuff():
    rect = []
    for i in range(5):
        rect.append([...])
    return rect
```

Comment: I cannot follow you. what do you mean with "I cannot store a list from the loop into a single variable like rect" ?  why can't you? are there any errors? why is this tagged `lua` only? isn't your problem in JavaScript? the Lua part looks ok. I'm not a JS expert but your for loop looks very much like a Lua for loop, not like a JavaScript for loop. this function expects a JavaScript function

Answer (score 0):

Let's take at your code.

You call [splash:jsfunc](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-jsfunc). This function converts JavaScript into a Lua callable. It takes a single argument. A string that defines a JavaScript function.

```
yourString = [[
  function () {
    for i=1, 5 do
      var rect = document.querySelector(string.format('checkbox[number="%d"]'), i).getClientRects()[0];
      return {[rect.left]: rect.top};
    end
  }
]]
```

This looks like some weird mix of Lua and JavaScript.

This is how a JavaScript for loop looks like

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // some code
}
```

This is how a Lua numeric for loop looks like:

Also what's the point of using return in a loop without any condition? This will be executed after the first cycle with i = 1. That's probably not what you want.

So fix the loop so it is JavaScript. Create a Object or Array and return that after the loop is complete.

Comment: It's from the docs here: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html which provides the sample I used but with my amendments. So you're saying the code in `function` is javascript? Okay! I'm assuming I have to create an empty array outside the loop, and store the values within the loop to the array. Then return outside the loop? Also, what's the equivalent to `string.format` in javascript?

Comment: well then your amendments are incorrect. currently you have a mix of  JavaScript and Lua where JavaScript is expected. you need to know Lua and JavaScript if you want to embed JavaScript code into Lua scripts. please understand that I won't write another JavaScript tutorial for you. there's already more than enough content online. please search the web for resources.

Comment: No that's fine - seems there's no equivalent to `string.format` for javascript.